# Why do some pilots call a go-around an 'overshoot'?

Tags: phraseology, go-around

A couple of months ago I was watching some [Ice Pilots NWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Pilots_NWT) re-runs, and I noticed they kept saying 'overshoot' when talking about a go-around. Is this standard Canadian phraseology? Or is it perhaps old phraseology? Or is it simply reworded for the benefit of the TV audience?

I'm not asking about the meaning of the word 'overshoot' which is quite clear, but it was being used were every pilot I know would use the word 'go-around', i.e. calling "overshoot, overshoot, overshoot" when shoving the throttles forward.

Comment: because overshooting the touch-down limit is the most common reason for a go-around maybe?

Comment: @ratchetfreak while that might be true, given the context, I'm fairly certain they called the action an 'overshoot' rather than a 'go-around'.

Comment: I've never heard that terminology, but a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=%22overshoot%22+%22go+around%22) suggests it can indeed mean "go-around" in British, Australian and (presumably) Canadian aviation lingo.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at the [Glossary for Pilots and Air Traffic Services Personnel (TP 11958E)](http://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/opssvs/secretariat-terminology-glossary-744.htm) at the Government of Canada web site, the definitions of overshoot and go-around are

> overshoot
>
> (1) To pass beyond the limit of the runway or landing field when
>   trying to land.
>
> Fr: dépasser
>
> (2) Other expression for: go-around

and

> “Go around”
>
> An expression used in radiocommunications to instruct a pilot to
>   abandon an approach or landing.
>
> Fr: « Remettez les gaz »
>
> go-around
>
> The procedure followed by a pilot who decides to abandon an approach
>   or landing.
>
> Fr: remise des gaz

Plus, looking at various Flight Test Guides listed at the [Canadian Government Air Transportation site](http://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/publications/menu.htm#training) it appears that pilots in Canadian flight schools are taught "overshoot" procedures for missed approaches (vice go-around).

Seeing as you were watching a reality TV show dealing with Canadian pilots, it is not surprising they use the terminology they were most likely taught in flight school (in Canada).

Comment: Cool, thanks for digging that up!

Comment: the quotes around "bush pilots" meaning you don't consider them real bush pilots? (just curious about your punctuation there. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Overshoot could be, also, when the pilot is not able to intercept the localizer, due to a sharp bank, or faster than usual, missing to intercept it. e.g.: The crew overshot the localizer, then they decided to start a new approach procedure.