# What was the motivation for revoking the licence to the pilots of Northwest flight 188?

Tags: air-traffic-control, commercial-aviation, pilot-certification

[This video](https://youtu.be/Ki9RK_JDtIg) describes [Northwest flight 188](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwest_Airlines_Flight_188), where two pilots overshot their destination by 150 miles, without contacting ATC for an hour. They cited 'cockpit distractions' as the reason and subsequently, both had their licenses permanently revoked.

***What exactly was the license removal be for?*** Overshooting the runway? Not contacting ATC for an hour? And what are the quantitative rules on this, i.e. how long would you have to not contact ATC for or how many miles off course would you have to go to get your license revoked liked these two did (in a commercial setting)?

Comment: Overshooting the intended destination isn't exactly a [runway overshoot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25695/753), whether you're using the US or (apparently) UK meaning of the term "overshoot".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this](http://edition.cnn.com/2009/US/10/27/airliner.fly.by/index.html) CNN article the FAA revoked their licences with a letter containing the following reasons (emphasis mine):

> The letter said the pilots were "**extremely reckless**."
>
> "Not only did you not comply with ... [air traffic controller] instructions, you did not even monitor the aircraft's air-ground radios," the letter said. "You were disengaged and impervious to the serious threat to your own safety, as well as the safety of people for whom you are responsible. This is a **total dereliction and disregard for your duties**."
>
> [...]
>
> The FAA said the revocations cite several violations of regulations, including **failure to comply with air traffic control and clearances** and **operating carelessly and recklessly**.

---

As Adam pointed out in the comments, this would violate [FAR 91.13](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.13):

> **§ 91.13 Careless or reckless operation.**
>
> (a) Aircraft operations for the purpose of air navigation. No person may operate an aircraft in a careless or reckless manner so as to endanger the life or property of another.
>
> (b) Aircraft operations other than for the purpose of air navigation. No person may operate an aircraft, other than for the purpose of air navigation, on any part of the surface of an airport used by aircraft for air commerce (including areas used by those aircraft for receiving or discharging persons or cargo), in a careless or reckless manner so as to endanger the life or property of another.

Comment: I take it there is no regulation set in stone and the FAA has leeway to decide what *extremely reckless* means on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: @AEhere yes, I would assume so, too. There won't be any *quantitative rules* for this. The authorities (in this case FAA) will evaluate the severity of the incidence and then make a decision, which can however be appealed by the pilots.

Comment: @AEhere That was my question. I wonder if these pilots did appeal and what the full story really is...

Comment: @Cloud have you read the wikipedia article and the references? what is it missing there that you are wondering "what the full story really is"?

Comment: @Federico Yes.. why was there was only 30 minutes' worth of information on the voice recorder? What exactly were they doing on their laptops? Why did none of the cabin crew say anything sooner? (Or any passengers for that matter) Do the pilots in question still fly in any capacity today? If not, what is their profession(s)? Were police forces present when the aircraft landed?

Comment: Their distraction cover story was quite unbeleivable.  Most professional pilots will tell you the likely truth was they both fell asleep. It's the explanation that makes the most sense.  The crew of a CRJ200 once both dozed off following a departure from an airport in Hawaii, for about 15 min.  One was just exhausted from circumstances that resulted in poor sleep the night before, and the other had undiagnosed sleep apnea and depending on coffee.  The 188 crew likely decided that taking the heat for inattention was better than admitting they fell asleep; didn't work out for them.

Comment: @Cloud It's possible for the capt to reset the CVR, which erases it, but which is a very very bad thing to do.  Which would explain only 30 min recorded and would be another large strike against them.  The sanction was pretty severe, especially for the FO, and I'm convinced it was because the authorities had surmised what really happened and were pretty unhappy with both of them sticking to an implausible story line.  If they had passed out and admitted so, they would have gone for medical assessments but probably would have had a better outcome.  Someone gave them very bad advice I think,

Comment: @JohnK That's what I've always thought. But I think screwing around on their computers is actually *worse* than falling asleep.

Comment: @JohnK Thanks for the clarification, that really makes a lot more sense to me now :)

Comment: @Cloud It's interesting. Aviation is one of those fields where, because decisions are life and death, trying to BS your way out of trouble rarely works.  Screw ups made in good faith, even things like dozing off, (which people in cars do all the time) usually get the screwer uper cut a bit of slack insofar as the remedial actions will be rehabilitative as opposed to banishment from the trade.  It's the liars that really get hammered.

Comment: If this had been a private pilot in a C550, he may have merely gotten a slap on the wrist, but probably would have had some sort of adverse action taken. The big issue here is flying passengers for hire in conjunction with ignoring (sleeping through) ATC clearances. THAT is why the action was so severe.